# How to map q for saving and quitting?

Tags: key-bindings, macro

I was reading the Vi documentation, by Joy and Horton and on section 6, 6.9 Macros they give a way to map q to save and quit:
`:map q :wq^V^VCR CR`

When trying that out in Vim it creates a new file ^V^V but it doesn't save and quit. Do you know how to do this in Vim?

I am trying to use .vimrc for this.

Comment: You should read the documentation of the tool you are actually using.

Comment: Isn't that what `ZZ` does out of the box?

Comment: ZZ is a little different, it only saves if there are changes. So it's actually better, I was just curious about how to do it in Vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only for `normal` mode:

```
nnoremap q :<C-u>wq<CR>
```

or

```
nnoremap q <cmd>wq<CR>
```

PS, be aware with mapped `q` you will have trouble to work with macro recordings.

Comment: I don’t think the C-u in the first mapping is strictly necessary.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, if one doesn't care about `1q`, `34q` and any other count provided

Answer (score 2):

The answer of @MaximKim is the modern one.

When [Joy and Horton](https://www.ele.uri.edu/faculty/vetter/Other-stuff/vi/vi-intro.pdf) say at paragraph 6.9:

```
:map q :wq^V^VCR CR
```

They actually mean:

`:map q :wq`<kbd>Ctrl v</kbd><kbd>Ctrl v</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

The document you are reading is about vi and not Vim

In Vim it is enough to do:
`:map q :wq`<kbd>Ctrl v</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: That's very interesting, can you just copy paste that into a .vimrc?

Comment: @MiguelCortes no, won't work if you copy and paste. You need to press the actual keys in Vim. See `:help i_CTRL-V` for more information.

Comment: @Friedrich What happens if I write this in my .vimrc: map q :wq <C-v><C-v><CR><CR>? Will it work?

Comment: @MiquelCortes, for the `.vimrc` the best is to write what Maxim Kim proposes `map q <cmd>wq<CR>` or `map q :wq^M` where the `^M` is obtained by hitting Ctrl-v Enter.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt You mean map q :wq<C-m><CR> because map q :wq^M would not work on the .vimrc. It would be equivalent to map q :wq<C-v><CR>.

Comment: @MiquelCortes `map q :wq^M` (where `^M` is obtained by typing <Ctrl-v>Enter) do work on my `.vimrc` file. But again the best solution is to do `nnoremap q <cmd>wq<CR>` or as romainl says use the standard `ZZ` ;-)

Comment: @MiguelCortes I `source`d `map q :wq <C-v><C-v><CR><CR>` and it creates a file called `^V`. So it does something but not what you want. You can easily test these things yourself, btw.

Comment: You are right, thanks for testing it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

(cross-posted from SO)

First things first: Vim is Vim, not Vi. They have lots of things in common but even more differences. If you absolutely want to learn from a book, pick [a book about Vim](https://pragprog.com/titles/dnvim2/practical-vim-second-edition/), not [a book about Vi](https://www.ele.uri.edu/faculty/vetter/Other-stuff/vi/vi-intro.pdf).

Your problem, beside using the wrong book, is that you don't read it carefully. `^V` is not the `^` character followed by the `V` character, it is the literal representation of `CTRL+V`. In the given example, you are told to…

1. enter the command-line with `:`:

   ```
   :
   ```
2. insert `map q :wq`:

   ```
   :map q :wq
   ```
3. press `^V` (`CTRL+V`) two times (maybe a Vi thing, you only need to do it once in Vim),
4. press `Carriage Return` once so that its literal value (`^M`) is inserted:

   ```
   :map q :wq^M
   ```
5. press `Carriage Return` one more time to execute the command you just typed.

The actual mapping is:

```
map q :wq^M
```

where `^M` is a literal `CTRL+M` character, not:

```
map q :wq^V^VCR CR
```

where `^` is `^`, `V` is `V`, etc. It is no wonder that your mapping is doing all sorts of crazy things as it is pure gibberish.

Just use the built-in `ZZ` next time.

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't think there is a wrong book on Vi. I knew it was not going to work, I just wanted to try it out. BTW, most of the information of the book is applicable to Vim as well, just some implementation details are not.

Comment: The difference between "most of the information" and "all of the information" is what makes that Vi book the wrong book versus an actual Vim book. And I don't think you knew it was not going to work.

Comment: I assumed it was not going to work, it's different than knowing. For that I would have to be an expert on Vi and Vim, even having read their source code. I doubt you are that good neither.

Comment: Thanks for the lecture on ^V<CR>. I don't think it was as clear in the manual as you say.